# CalDav protocol have analogs?

Tags: caldav

I know what CalDav it's protocol for sync calendar, but I need know, whether there are analogues.
What is the difference between them? 
I tried search internet but I didn't find any information.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one Internet/IETF standard for calendar sync, and that is CalDAV. Aka [RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791).

Microsoft has a set of proprietary protocols, including Exchange Web Services, which also do calendar sync.

Google calendar also has an own proprietary 'Google Calendar API', but also supports CalDAV.

The question for the difference between them is too generic. Be more specific in what differences you are interested in.
Generalising a lot, most of the stuff out there is built on top of the iCalendar/iTIP standards. Most services today can be accessed using CalDAV, unless you connect to Microsoft stuff. They do the traditional lock-in and you may even need to license the protocol from them.